# OpenCV Mask Strange Pixel Counting Pattern

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

[image: Frame]
[image: Mask]

**Goal:** My code below first creates a mask of the red lines. Then, starting at the center green dot, the code iterates one space at a time to the right until it finds a white pixel on the mask (at a fixed height). This pixel is signified by the green dot on the right. This process is then repeated with the left side to find the first left white pixel. I have also set up a counter to track the amount of even vs. odd numbered pixels the program finds during each search.

**Problem:** Although this code seems to be working, my problem is that when iterating to find the **right** white pixel, most of these pixels are always **even**. It seems to me that the distribution should be 50-50 for the percentage of even and odd pixels here. Similarly, when iterating to find the **left** white pixel, most of these pixels are always **odd**.

A common output from this program: *Right Even: 795, Right Odd: 67, Left Even: 46, Left Odd: 808*

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2



time.sleep(.1)

def callback(x):
    pass


ilowH = 75
ihighH = 100
ilowS = 120
ihighS = 255
ilowV = 0
ihighV = 255


rightEven = 0
rightOdd = 0
leftEven = 0
leftOdd = 0

width = 1280
height = 720

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, width)
cap.set(4, height)

def dot(point, image):
    cv2.circle(image, point, 5, (0,255,0), -2)

while(True):
    # grab the frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    #Create mask
    frame = 255 - frame
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_hsv = np.array([ilowH, ilowS, ilowV])
    higher_hsv = np.array([ihighH, ihighS, ihighV])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hsv, higher_hsv)
    frame = 255 - frame
    
    
    center = int(width/2)
    dot((center,int(height/2)), frame)
    currRightPoint = center
    currLeftPoint = center
    rightPointFound = False
    leftPointFound = False
    

    
    while(rightPointFound == False):
        currRightPoint = currRightPoint + 1
        if (mask[int(height / 2)][currRightPoint] == 255):
            rightPointFound = True
            dot((currRightPoint, int(height/2)), frame)
            
            if (currRightPoint % 2 == 0):
                rightEven = rightEven + 1
            else:
                rightOdd = rightOdd + 1
            
        if (currRightPoint == width - 1):
            rightPointFound = True
            

    while(leftPointFound == False):
        currLeftPoint = currLeftPoint - 1
        if (mask[int(height / 2)][currLeftPoint] == 255):
            leftPointFound = True
            dot((currLeftPoint, int(height/2)), frame)
            
            if (currLeftPoint % 2 == 0):
                leftEven = leftEven + 1
            else:
                leftOdd = leftOdd + 1
            
        if (currLeftPoint == 0):
            leftPointFound = True


    print('Center: ' + str(center) + ', Right: ' + str(currRightPoint) + ', Left: ' + str(currLeftPoint))



    # show thresholded image
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF # large wait time to remove freezing
    if k == 113 or k == 27:
        break

print('Right Even: ' + str(rightEven) + ', Right Odd: ' + str(rightOdd))
print('Left Even: ' + str(leftEven) + ', Left Odd: ' + str(leftOdd))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

For this application, the exact pixel count between the left and right edges is very important, so I need the exact values. Since these values aren't 50% even and 50% odd, I believe I am not finding the most exact points.

**Solution Attempt 1)** I have tried using different webcams in the case that the camera is up-scaling from a resolution lower than 720p, but the exact same results have occured.

**Solution Attempt 2)** I have also tried iterating starting from the left side of the screen to the left edge of the left line. Since I was iterating to the right, most of these pixel values turned up even.

Any insight into the problem would be appreciated!

Comment: Could it have something to do with the [Bayer filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) of your camera? If that's the case, you should find the opposite pattern if you use blue instead of red lines.

Comment: To have an easier time finding red to create the mask (since red is both at the beginning and end of the color wheel), I am actually inverting the frame to turn the red into a blue before creating the mask. Then, I invert the frame back to turn the blue back into the red. Can this still be the problem, considering this?

Comment: It could also be due to compression. Often, only luminance is encoded at full resolution because this is where the human eye is most sensitive; hue might be encoded at only half resolution.

Comment: Consider using YUV instead of HSV, because it's not circular. Red = low U, high V.

Comment: Just adjusted the mask to only filter based off of luminance, but the problem persisted just as before unfortunately. Thanks, I will check out that color space! Do you have any other suggestions as to what it could be?

Comment: Looking carefully at your black and white image, I do see a lot of 2-pixel stairsteps, especially on the left edge of the leftmost line. So it's clearly not an issue with your code, and my money is on the Bayer filter. If a 720p camera indeed has a sensor of 720 physical pixels in the vertical direction, only a quarter of its pixels would be used to capture red light, so you effectively get only half the resolution in the red.